# If we are in the car, we see the trees on the street are moving backwards. Do the trees have kinetic energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, inertial-frames, observers

I copied this question from the internet. I thought about it but I can't make out the meaning of the statement.

Comment: Seems reasonable, given how much damage the trees will do to the car on impact.

Comment: The kinetic energy depends on the reference frame. As does mass. But the total energy remains constant. Refer: Relativistic Energy formula, Einstein's relativity papers of 1905 (4th one I think).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the trees have kinetic energy in the car's frame of reference.  Kinetic energy is a frame-dependent quantity (i.e., it is not Lorentz invariant).